# Stopping imap_expunge from deleting unread messages

Tags: php, imap

I have written a script to get all the read messages with a specific part in the subject. When I set them for delete and then purge it, it also removes the unread messages with the part in the subject. How can I prevent this?

```
    $check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($connection);
echo "Messages before delete: " . $check->Nmsgs . "<br />\n";


$count = imap_num_msg( $connection );
for ( $msgno = 1; $msgno <= $count; $msgno ++ ) {

    $headers = imap_headerinfo( $connection, $msgno );
    if ( $headers->Unseen == " " && strpos( $headers->subject, 'Urgente' ) !== false) {

        echo $msgno;
        $imapresult = imap_mail_move( $connection, $msgno, 'INBOX/old' );
        $del = imap_delete( $connection, "$msgno");
        $check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($connection);
        echo "Messages after  delete: " . $check->Nmsgs . "<br />\n";
    }

}

imap_expunge($connection);
$check = imap_mailboxmsginfo($connection);
echo "Messages after expunge: " . $check->Nmsgs . "<br />\n";

imap_close($connection);
```

Comment: Don't call imap_delete on message you don't want deleted?

Comment: Unless you're saying that messages that you do not flag for delete are being deleted, I think Max nailed it.